# Activity is closed when AsyncTask is using database

Tags: android

My Activity opens a database in onResume() and close it in onPause(). When Activity starts, many AsyncTasks which use that database execute. When I pressed Back button, database was closed and errors appear because AsyncTask is using it. What is solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't close the database. Have your db helper class be a singleton and access it from your activities as needed. When you process dies, the database will be properly closed. Do make sure you are closing your cursors though.

Comment: "When you process dies, the database will be properly closed" << do you mean when Application was terminated, the database will be closed automatically?
ok, I'm using singleton and where to open and close?

Comment: Yes. Open you first need to use it, don't close.

Comment: Not work =.=. Always have "Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed" exception. My App uses List View, Cursor, AsyncTasks, no use startManagingQuery, no close anything. AsyncTask requery cursor in onPostExecute(). I read many questions on StackOverflow but still don't have a best solution for this. I'm trying other ways...

Comment: As I said, you need to close your cursors. Use try/finally to close each cursor after you are done with it. The exception you mention should have a stack trace, pointing to the place where you opened your cursor, so you can identify the leak. Keep in mind that closing the database != closing cursors.

Comment: It works! I followed your advice, close each cursor after done with it. It also solved the main question above! Thank you very much. :D

Answer (score 1):

This is the possible solution I can think of...

```
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //before database close
            if(asyncTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                  asyncTask.cancel(true);
            }
            //close your database
   }
```

calling cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) doesn't necessarily stop the background thread. But what you can possibly do in your doInBackground method...

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(!(isCancelled())){
            //if async task not cancelled
            //Database still open and good to use
        } else {
            //database is closed
        }

        return null;
}
```

Hope this atleast give some direction to solve your problem.